# html/css Contenteditable on span when clicking it

Tags: html, css

```
  <div class="title-area">
        <h3><span class="editAttributeInput" id="Name" contenteditable="true" ><%= Name %></span></h3>
    </div>
```

I want to edit this title by clicking it. 
This works fine.
But also when I click to the right of this element, I trigger contenteditable. I do not want that.

I do not want to set a width on the element, because I want the editable field to only be as big as the word inside (no fixed size).
Setting a width on the .title-area does not help either.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: h3 { display: inline }

Comment: nope, that did not make a difference

Comment: where is click handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your example and it worked. (clicks on other elements are not triggering contenteditable) the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2uys8mp/)

Below is a solution with jquery. (can be helpful)

```
<div class="title-area">
    <h3>
        <span tabindex="999" class="editAttributeInput" id="Name">name</span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

'tabindex="999"' is for focus and blur to work.

```
$('#Name').focus(function (e) {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', true);
});
$('#Name').blur(function (e) {
    $(this).removeAttr('contenteditable');
});
```